# Remove element of specific class from list in R

Tags: r, list, removeclass

I expect there is a simple way to do this but after searching couldn't find an answer. I have a list and want to remove elements of a specific class.

For example say I have the list

```
tempList <- list(2,4,'a', 7, 'f')
```

How could I remove all character entries to just leave a list of 2, 4 and 7.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
> tempList[!sapply(tempList, function(x) class(x) == "character")]
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 7
```

Note that this is equivalent.

```
tempList[sapply(tempList, function(x) class(x) != "character")]
```

If you need to use this a lot, you can make it into a function.

```
classlist <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, class)
}

tempList[classlist(tempList) != "character"]
```

or

```
classlist2 <- function(x) {
  x[!sapply(x, function(m) class(m) == "character")]
}

classlist2(tempList)
```

Comment: was just about to post that.

Answer (score 4):

```
Filter(is.numeric, tempList)
```

is a tidy, functional, way of writing this.